Is P4Studio essential for P4 programming on a Tofino switch?
I am looking to perform P4 programming for academic purposes and recently acquired a used Tofino-based switch, the Wedge-100BF-32X. My question is: Is P4Studio essential for P4 programming on this switch, or are there alternative tools or methods available?
I have tried contacting Intel to inquire access grant to P4Studio, but it was found to be infeasible (probably because they killed Tofino a couple years ago and thus hesitate to provide additional support)

Tofino is still supported and receives updates, but mainly for partners with access to P4Studio.
Intel's P4Studio and TNA code are only available through their partner program or licensing agreement, so access is limited.
An alternative option is to use BMv2 with p4c for testing P4 programs in a simulated environment, although it cannot be used with Tofino hardware. Another alternative is to use the Barefoot Open-Tofino platform, which provides an open-source framework for working with Tofino switches.
https://github.com/barefootnetworks/Open-Tofino
